# Combining Covariances of Two Sets

Tags: statistics, algorithms, covariance

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance), the formula for combining the covariances of two sets is:
$$C_X=C_A+C_B+(\overline{x}_A-\overline{x}_B)(\overline{y}_A-\overline{y}_B) \cdot\frac{n_An_B}{n_X} $$
where:

- $A$ and $B$ are the first and second sets.
- $C$ is the Covariance.
- $n$ is the number of samples.
- $n_X = n_A + n_B$.
- $x$ and $y$ are the features.

I implemented this formula by splitting one dataset into two equal sets, for testing purposes, yet the result is *quite* different from the original dataset covariance.

Now, let $M_{AB}$ be this part of the above formula:

$$(\overline{x}_A-\overline{x}_B)(\overline{y}_A-\overline{y}_B) \cdot\frac{n_An_B}{n_X}$$

Looking at [this implementation](https://carstenschelp.github.io/2019/05/12/Online_Covariance_Algorithm_002.html), the author basically applied the following formula:

$$
C_X = \frac{(C_A \color{red}{\cdot n_A})  + (C_B \color{red}{\cdot n_B}) + M_{AB}}{\color{red}{n_X}}
$$

which gives the **correct combined covariance**!.

---

I could not understand how the latter is **derived or achieved algebraically**? Or if it's even similar to the former formula? because there are extra $\color{red}{n_A}$ and $\color{red}{n_B}$ that are added to the second formula!

Your help is appreciated.